# Excluding a folder from the home directory with rsync exclude list

Tags: macos, backup, rsync, exclude

I am trying to set up `rsync` for OS X 10.8.4 using an exclude file. However, it does not recognize the paths I want to exclude.

I want to copy the user `ABC`'s home directory to a folder called `Backup_Mac` on a mounted external drive.

```
rsync -av --progress --exclude-from='/Users/ABC/excludelist.txt' /Users/ABC /Volumes/Backup_Mac
```

`excludelist.txt` contains

```
- /Users/ABC/Dropbox/
```

It is not excluding the Dropbox folder.

Now if I change the exclude file to

```
- Dropbox/
```

it is excluding `ABC/Dropbox` but also all other folders named Dropbox elsewhere in the file tree. This is not what I want – I want to exclude only the folder `ABC/Dropbox` but include any other folders called `Dropbox`, e.g. `ABC/Application Support/Dropbox`.

Any hint on how to achieve that? How do I have to specify the exclude path, relative to the folder backed up, or relative to root?

Comment: Does your list literally contain a hyphen and a space before the path?

Comment: It does. I tried different variations (removing hyphen and/or space), none of them work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put, `rsync` uses relative paths to determine what to exclude. From [the `rsync` manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rsync.1.html):

> If the pattern starts with a / then it is anchored to a particular spot in  the  hierarchy  of files,  otherwise it is matched against the end of the pathname.  This is similar to a leading ^ in regular expressions.  Thus "/foo" would match a file named "foo" at either the  "root  of the transfer" (for a global rule) (…)

The simplest way to work around this is to use `--relative` / `-R`, which lets you exclude Dropbox like so:

```
rsync -avR --exclude='/Users/alex/Dropbox' /Users/alex /Volumes/Backup_Mac
```

The name `relative` refers to how `rsync` sends the paths and therefore doesn't have anything to do with specifying absolute exclude patterns.

Note that this creates the full directory tree `/Volumes/Backup_Mac/Users/alex/`, but that's not a terribly bad thing in your case.

Comment: That is the solution, indeed. Many thanks my friend. It also works using the 'exclude file', awesome!

Comment: **Bonus Followup:** Does one need to exclude the Volumes directory? I'm doing the following, but the progress messages look as though it is considering files within the Volumes directory: `rsync --archive --progress --verbose --inplace -- exclude '/Volumes'  / /Volumes/NetBackup/iMacRsync/`

Comment: @flipdoubt Since `/Volumes` is a direct child of the root, yes, you'd have to exclude it when you want to sync `/`.